# Save hash data with KECCAK-256 then reverse the process in PHP

Tags: blockchain, hash, keccak, php

I am saving data hashed with keccak-256 in Solidity and I am trying read that data with PHP, but cant seem to find any good solutions.

I can get PHP to read off the data but I cant arrive at the same resulting hash to compare the results from what PHP gives to what Solidity gives in order to confirm what the data is.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 4):

Hashing is one-way: If you have text you can create a hash, but if you have a hash you can't use it to recreate the text.

Comment: Or put another way, you cannot turn a burger into a cow.

Comment: An alternative is encryption, which is reversible operation.

Comment: I understand that.. I have worded it poorly. You cant undo it but you can verify the data is the same by hashing the same string on the PHP side.

Example: in solidity
take the word 'apple'
convert it to hex  '6170706c65'
hash using keccak256('6170706c65'') resulting in 
0x85dca312121b082f39dd34192d69dffd93c0add33dac13f7846f2975fba845c6

PHP knows what the result of apple should be using the same procedure 
it knows that 'apple' should become
.0x85dca312121b082f39dd34192d69dffd93c0add33dac13f7846f2975fba845c6'

it only needs to compare the 2 results
That is what I am trying to do

Comment: You might use a library like [Ethereum-PHP](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) which is [documented](http://ethereum-php.org/dev/).

Comment: @RobHitchens You can turn a burger into a cow. If the burger has the cow dna you can clone it. And voila, you now have a cow.